# Existensial types in Scala

Tags: scala, types, enums, existential-type

Little confusing about existential types.

This works for me:

```
def valueOf(c: Class[_], name: String) {
  type C = Class[T] forSome {type T <: Enum[T]}
  Enum.valueOf(c.asInstanceOf[C], name)
}
```

but this does not:

```
def valueOf(c: Class[_], name: String) {
  type T = T forSome {type T <: Enum[T]}
  Enum.valueOf(c.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], name)
}
```

In my mind both expressions are equivalent to:

```
Enum.valueOf(z.asInstanceOf[Class[T] forSome {type T <: Enum[T]}], name)
```

But Scala says that it's in my mind only:

```
inferred type arguments [T] do not conform to method valueOf's type parameter bounds [T <: Enum[T]]
         Enum.valueOf(c.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], name)
              ^
```

Comment: after so many years I realize how stupid my question was :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the difference between the following two expressions:

```
Enum.valueOf(x.asInstanceOf[Class[X] forSome { type X <: Enum[X] }], name)
```

And:

```
Enum.valueOf(x.asInstanceOf[Class[X forSome { type X <: Enum[X] }]], name)
```

Now think about how the type parameter `T` of `valueOf` will be inferred in each of these cases. In the first case, we've got an `X` that we know is a subtype of `Enum[X]`, and we're all set. In the second case, on the other hand, `T` would have to be `X forSome { type X <: Enum[X] }`, and crucially this type is not a subtype of `Enum[X forSome { type X <: Enum[X] }]`, so we haven't satisfied the constraint on `T`.

The problem is that your second example is equivalent to the latter.

---

As a footnote, this would work just fine if `Enum` were covariant in its type parameter. Take the following simplified example:

```
trait Foo[A]
trait Bar[A]

def foo[A <: Bar[A]](f: Foo[A]) = f

def x: Foo[X] forSome { type X <: Bar[X] } = ???
def y: Foo[Y forSome { type Y <: Bar[Y] }] = ???
```

Now `foo(x)` will compile, but `foo(y)` won't, just as in your code. But change `Bar` a bit:

```
trait Foo[A]
trait Bar[+A]

def foo[A <: Bar[A]](f: Foo[A]) = f

def x: Foo[X] forSome { type X <: Bar[X] } = ???
def y: Foo[Y forSome { type Y <: Bar[Y] }] = ???
```

Now they'll both compile. I'd guess that this has something to do with the reason that we have such strong intuitions about your two examples being equivalent.

---

As another footnote (in response to [gzmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149944/gzm0)'s [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396572/existensial-types-in-scala#comment27035771_18403715)), consider the following:

```
scala> trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]]
defined trait Foo

scala> class MyFoo extends Foo[MyFoo]
defined class MyFoo

scala> val myFoo = new MyFoo
myFoo: MyFoo = MyFoo@3ee536d

scala> myFoo: (X forSome { type X <: Foo[X] })
res0: X forSome { type X <: Foo[X] } = MyFoo@3ee536d

scala> myFoo: Foo[MyFoo]
res1: Foo[MyFoo] = MyFoo@3ee536d
```

Let's suppose that `X forSome { type X <: Foo[X] }` *were* a subtype of `Foo[X forSome { type X <: Foo[X] }]` (ignoring for a moment the fact that the latter isn't even a valid type). Then we'd be able to write the following:

```
myFoo: Foo[X forSome { type X <: Foo[X] }]
```

But `Foo` is invariant, so if we have some thing that's an instance of both `Foo[A]` and `Foo[B]`, then it must be the case that `A =:= B`. But it's definitely not the case that `MyFoo =:= (X forSome { type X <: Foo[X] })`. Not sure all of that is any less confusing, but it's how I convinced myself that the compiler knows what it's doing here.

Comment: I do not understand why `X forSome { type X <: Enum[X] }` is not subtype of `Enum[X forSome { type X <: Enum[X] }]` (in my mind, `X <: Enum[X]` and the same constraints apply recursively). Can you explain? Are we running into one of the strange restrictions of F-bound polymorphism?