# Type alias to A is not equivalent to A?

Tags: scala, type-alias

This code compiles just as fine:

```
type Named[A] = (String, A)

def foo[A](a: A) = {}

trait Elem[A]

val m = Map[String, Elem[_]]()

m.foreach(e => foo[Named[Elem[_]]](e))
```

However this one doesn't:

```
type NamedElem[A] = Named[Elem[A]]

m.foreach(e => foo[NamedElem[_]](e))
```

The error message doesn't really explain me why:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Elem[_])
 required: NamedElem[_]
    (which expands to)  (String, Elem[_$2]) forSome { type _$2 }
              Map[String, Elem[_]]().foreach(e => foo[NamedElem[_]](e))
                                                                    ^
```

So apparently `NamedElem[A]` is not `Named[Elem[A]]`. Is this a supposed behavior? Or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's related to existential types only. This compiles just fine:

```
type Named[A] = (String, A)

def foo[A](a: A) = {}

trait Elem[A]

val m = Map[String, Elem[Int]]()

m.foreach(e => foo[Named[Elem[Int]]](e))

type NamedElem[A] = Named[Elem[A]]

m.foreach(e => foo[NamedElem[Int]](e))
```

`_` is just a syntax sugar for `forSome`. In your case:

`NamedElem[_]` expands to the `(String, Elem[T]) forSome { type T }`, while
`Named[Elem[_]]` expands to the `(String, Elem[T] forSome { type T })`

So yes, `NamedElem[_]` and `Named[Elem[_]]` are different types.

You may find more info in my old question: [Existensial types in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396572/existensial-types-in-scala)

Comment: Thank you @dk14, so `Named[Elem[A]]` isn't `NamedElem[A]` when `A` is an existential type. Do you think we can prevent the difference? I mean, is there a way to declare `type NamedElem[A]` which is completely equivalent to `Named[Elem[A]]`?

Comment: @RyoichiroOka It _is_ equivalent for every type `A`. The problem is that `_` is not a type.

Comment: There is only a way to declare appropriate existential (if you really need them) - `type NamedElem_ = Named[Elem[T] forSome { type T}]`. As @Alexey Romanov said - it's already equivalent for non-high-order generics. Trying to unify it has no sense...just look at desugaring - `_` is just a syntax sugar to `forSome`, not type itself. Existential type definition here is `{type T}` inside `forSome`, not even `T` inside `Elem[T]` (it's just a ref)

Comment: `forSome` is attaching to the nearest `[_]` braces so it's actually  works as expected