# existential types declarations in Scala

Tags: scala, existential-type

What is the difference between the following existential types declarations:

```
trait A[T <: A[T]]

1. def existentialErr(arg: A[T forSome{type T <: A[T]}]): Unit =()
2. def existentialOk(arg: A[T] forSome{type T <: A[T]}): Unit =()
```

Point 1 is generates the following compile time error:

> type arguments `[T forSome { type T <: packagename.A[T] }]` do not conform to trait A's type parameter bounds `[T <: packagename.A[T]]`

Point 2 compiles without issue.

Generally this question is very similar to the following unanswered one:
[Confusion with existential types in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646416/confusion-with-existential-types-in-scala)

Reproduced on **Scala 2.11.6**

UPD: Travis Brown has provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403715/334519)

Comment: If I understand [this](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) correctly, then point 1 is an `A[Any]` and point 2 is an `A[T <: A[T]]`. I might be wrong though...

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18403715/334519) for some discussion of a similar case.